# How to get the first x leading binary digits of 5**x without big integer multiplication

Tags: math, floating-point

I want to efficiently and elegantly compute with perfect precision the first x leading binary digits of 5**x?

For example 5**20 is 10101101011110001110101111000101101011000110001. The first 8 leading binary digits is 10101101.

In my use case, x is only up to 1-60. I don't want to create a table. A solution using 64-bit integers would be fine. I just don't want to use big integers.

Comment: It's 60 bytes. A table is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> first x leading binary digits of 5**x without big integer multiplication
>
> efficiently and elegantly compute with perfect precision the first x leading binary digits of 5<sup>x</sup>?

"compute with perfect precision" leaves out `pow()`.  Too many implementations will return an imperfect result and FP math might not use 64 bit precision, even with `long double`.

---

Form an integer with a 64-bit whole number part `.ms` and a 64-bit fraction part `.ls`.  Then loop 60 times, multiply by 5 and diving by 2 as needed, to keep the leading bits from growing too big.

Note there is some precision lost in the *fraction*, with `N > 42`, yet that is not significant enough to affect the whole number part OP is seeking.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  uint64_t ms, ls;
} uint128;

// Simplifications possible here, leave for OP
uint128 times5(uint128 x) {
  uint128 y = x;
  for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
    // y += x
    y.ms += x.ms;  
    y.ls += x.ls;
    if (y.ls < x.ls) y.ms++;
  }
  return y;
}

uint128 div2(uint128 x) { 
  x.ls = (x.ls >> 1) | (x.ms << 63);
  x.ms >>= 1;
  return x;
}

int main(void) {
  uint128 y = {.ms = 1};
  uint64_t pow2 = 2;
  for (unsigned x = 1; x <= 60; x++) {
    y = times5(y);
    while (y.ms >= pow2) {
      y = div2(y);
    }
    printf("%2u %16" PRIX64 ".%016" PRIX64 "\n", x, y.ms, y.ls);
    pow2 <<= 1;
  }
}
```

Output

```
         whole part.fraction
 1                1.4000000000000000
 2                3.2000000000000000
 3                7.D000000000000000
 4                9.C400000000000000
...
57  14643E5AE44D12B.8F5FEE5AA432560D
58  32FA9BE33AC0AEC.E66FD3E29A7DD720
59  7F7285B812E1B50.401791B6823A99D0
60  9F4F2726179A224.501D762422C94044
    ^-------------^ This is the part OP is seeking.
```

The key to solving this task is: [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm).  Form an algorithm, (which is simply *5 and /2 as needed), and code a type and functions to do each small step.

---

Is a loop of 60 efficient? Perhaps not. Another approach would use [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Certainly would be worth it for large `N`, yet for `N == 60`, a loop was simple enough for a quick turn.

Comment: Note: the above code begins to generate approximate fraction results N > 42.  It just happens the these approximate fraction results do not foal the integer results.   A "perfect" calculation would need at least 140 bit math.

Answer (score 0):

5<sup>n</sup> = 2<sup>(-n)</sup> • 10<sup>n</sup>

Using this identity, we can easily compute the leading N base-2 digits of (the nearest integer to) any given power of 5.

This code example is in C, but it's the same idea in any other language.

Example output: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fs205DDzQR0gaLSo

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define STATIC_ASSERT(CONDITION) ((void)sizeof(int[(CONDITION) ? 1 : -1]))

uint64_t pow5_leading_digits(double power, uint8_t ndigits)
{
    STATIC_ASSERT(DBL_MANT_DIG <= 64);

    double pow5 = exp2(-power) * pow(10, power);

    const double binary_digits = ceil(log2(pow5));

    assert(ndigits <= DBL_MANT_DIG);

    if (!ndigits || binary_digits < 0)
        return 0;

    // If pow5 can fit in the number of digits requested, return it
    if (binary_digits <= ndigits)
        return pow5;
    // If pow5 is too big to return, divide by 2 until it fits
    if (binary_digits > DBL_MANT_DIG)
        pow5 /= exp2(binary_digits - DBL_MANT_DIG + 1);

    return (uint64_t)pow5 >> (DBL_MANT_DIG - ndigits);
}
```

Edit: Now limits the returned value to those exactly representable with `double`'s.

Comment: Won't this approach fail if you try working with a number that is too big to fit into a double or a long? I was under the impression that the question was about how to do this for arbitrary numbers of digits for arbitrarily large powers without using high-precision integers.

Comment: @templatetypedef It fails if you want more than 64 binary digits/bits, but it does handle numbers too large to fit in an unsigned long (see the part commented "if pow5 is too big to return, divide by 2 until it fits").

Comment: I might extend my answer with a C++ template function that returns a `std::bitset` of arbitrary length.

Comment: As for numbers too large to fit in a double, I do now notice I got that wrong, and so I should restrict the result to 53 bits. (Which also means the bitset idea is a lot more complicated than I was thinking, although I believe I could do something with an array of doubles instead of one).

Comment: What is the point of using `exp2(-power) * pow(10, power)` rather than `pow(5, power)`?

Comment: If you want to extract the leading bits of the significand of a double, there is no need to take the logarithm, just use frexp and ldexp. The entire routine can be `int e; return ldexp(frexp(pow(5, power), &e), ndigits);`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Comment 1) I was originally planning to make `power` and `pow5` integers and replace the `pow(10, power)` call with one to an integer exponentiation function, which I believe would allow for one additional bit of precision since I'd only be storing integer powers of 2 as doubles.

Comment: Comment 2) I haven't used the C math library very much, so I wasn't aware of `ldexp` and `frexp`. That is quite a bit simpler.

Comment: See my comment on your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47229929/how-to-get-the-first-x-leading-binary-digits-of-5x-without-big-integer-multipl/47232247?noredirect=1#comment81417701_47233229

Comment: Are you rewriting your answer? I'm leaving mine as-is for the moment b/c I wouldn't want to look like I'm taking credit for your ideas.